# I'm having trouble structuring data from a calendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The data is an array which contains the days and events alternating by week, so:

[1,2,3,4,5,'','','','green event','blue event','red event',8,9,10,11,12,'red event','white event','','','']

As you can see, sometimes there are more events per day, *the events in the array wrap back to the first event*

Which means day 1,2 and 3 have no events, day 4 has green and red, day five has blue.

I've been going at this for 8 hours straight.

here's my current code:

```js
// holds the current event in the loop
let eventCount = 0;
// a count that resets every time the event count is longer than the amount of days in a week
// the idea was to combine the same realevents as they have the same number if they're on the    // same day
let realEventCount = 0;
// array to contain all the dates
let trashdays = [];
// array to contain all the events
let trashEvents = [];
// chunks are meant to split the events by week
let newChunk = true;
let chunk = 0;

let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '', '', '', 'green event', 'blue event', 'red event', 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 'red event', 'white event', '', '', '']

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  // if the data is a date
  if (!isNaN(data[i]) && data[i] !== '') {
    trashdays.push(data[i]);

    if (newChunk) {
      chunk++;
      // reset reid when new chunk
      realEventCount = 0;
      newChunk = false;
    }
  } else {
    // every time data alternates from events to date numbers it becomes a new chunk
    newChunk = true;
  }

  // if data is an event or what passes as an empty event
  if (isNaN(data[i]) || data[i] === '') {
    trashEvents[eventCount] = {
      id: undefined,
      chunk: undefined,
      data: '',
      reid: undefined,
      day: undefined,
    };
    trashEvents[eventCount].id = eventCount;
    trashEvents[eventCount].data = data[i];
    trashEvents[eventCount].chunk = chunk;

    // this thing was for when it isn't an empty event, i'm probably wrong with the math
    // stuff, but it's trying to figure out how to know when the events wrap back
    if (isNaN(data[i])) {
      if (Math.floor(trashEvents[eventCount].id / trashEvents[eventCount].chunk) > 4) {
        // reset reid when the event is offset
        realEventCount = 0;
      }
      trashEvents[eventCount].reid = realEventCount;
      realEventCount++;
    }

    eventCount++;
  }
}

console.log(trashEvents)
```

Comment: _As you can see_ ; I do not understand your data array nor what are you trying to achieve. You need to be clear about what outcome you except on presented data.

Comment: There are obviously more events than there are days wdym @ikiK